# pragma omp shortcuts in c

Tags: c, global-variables, pragma

I have some global variables that I need to use inside a parallelized  section of my program. So I wrote this:

```
#define N 2000
int x[N], matrix[N][N]

int main(int argc, char **argv)   
...
#pragma omp parallel
{
  #pragma omp privatethread(x,matrix)
  #pragma omp for
  for(int k=0; k<100;++k)
    /*some function to modify values of x and matrix differently 
     from run to run*/
  ...
}
...
```

Is the part with **#pragma** equivalent to:

```
...
#pragma omp privatethread(x,matrix) parallel for
...
```

Is there a difference between declaring  **#pragma omp parallel** then **#pragma omp privatethread**  and declaring first  **#pragma omp privatethread** and then  **#pragma omp parallel for**?  Do i have to put a  {  after the privathread part?

```
#pragma omp privatethread(x,matrix)
{ //<-- here
#pragma omp for
```

Finally, is that a good way to work with large vectors in c or is it better to use malloc inside my pragma omp and remove the privatethread part? (please let me know if it's better that I ask this ending question in a new post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The below code gives you an error. Even if you remove the for.

```
...
#pragma omp privatethread(x,matrix) parallel for
...
```

The declaration must follow this syntax

```
#pragma omp threadprivate (list)
```

2.There is no difference between,

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp privatethread(list)
   //CODE
}
```

and

```
#pragma omp privatethread(list) 
#pragma omp parallel
{
  //CODE
}
```

As you can see you don't have to put { brackets after the  **#pragma omp privatethread** .This statement doesn't run any code in parallel it just makes the global scope variable local and persistent to a thread.